# Optimal way to synchronize database tables cross server

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I developed a tool to synchronize data across sql-servers. The tool is responsible for either updating or inserting records from the source table to the destination table. An insert should be executed on the rows that doesn't exist in the destination table. An update should be executed on the rows that already exists in the destination table.

Earlier I did the comparison between the tables in code, but this turned out to be very slow (at least the way I coded it). Now I'm using **one** sql query for inserting and **one** for updating. The performance is better but it's still slow. Below are my SQL commands. Do you see anything that could be optimized? Eg. can I use something other than an outer join that would be faster?

The update command:

```
UPDATE [Respondent]
SET [SampleGroupID] = ls.[SampleGroupID], [RespondentStatusTypeID] = ls.[RespondentStatusTypeID], [PilotTest] = ls.[PilotTest], [Username] = ls.[Username], [Password] = ls.[Password], [ImportUniqueID] = ls.[ImportUniqueID], [WORespID] = ls.[WORespID], [DateLastAnswered] = ls.[DateLastAnswered], [DateCreated] = ls.[DateCreated], [Email] = ls.[Email], [Phone] = ls.[Phone], [Name] = ls.[Name], [JobTitle] = ls.[JobTitle], [PhoneDirect] = ls.[PhoneDirect], [PhoneMobile] = ls.[PhoneMobile], [Fax] = ls.[Fax], [CompanyName] = ls.[CompanyName], [Department] = ls.[Department], [Address] = ls.[Address], [Address1] = ls.[Address1], [Address2] = ls.[Address2], [Zipcode] = ls.[Zipcode], [City] = ls.[City], [District] = ls.[District], [CountryCode] = ls.[CountryCode], [Country] = ls.[Country], [Info1] = ls.[Info1], [Info2] = ls.[Info2], [Info3] = ls.[Info3], [Info4] = ls.[Info4], [Info5] = ls.[Info5], [Info6] = ls.[Info6], [Info7] = ls.[Info7], [Info8] = ls.[Info8], [Info9] = ls.[Info9], [Info10] = ls.[Info10], [Info11] = ls.[Info11], [Info12] = ls.[Info12], [Info13] = ls.[Info13], [Info14] = ls.[Info14], [Info15] = ls.[Info15], [Info16] = ls.[Info16], [Info17] = ls.[Info17], [Info18] = ls.[Info18], [Info19] = ls.[Info19], [Info20] = ls.[Info20], [PublicIdentifier] = ls.[PublicIdentifier], [LockedByUser] = ls.[LockedByUser], [DialAttempts] = ls.[DialAttempts], [DialProbationExpires] = ls.[DialProbationExpires], [CATIScreenOptionID] = ls.[CATIScreenOptionID], [CATIPersonID] = ls.[CATIPersonID], [TotalDuration] = ls.[TotalDuration], [IsExternal] = ls.[IsExternal]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DBName].[dbo].[Respondent] ls LEFT OUTER JOIN [Respondent] adm
ON ls.RespondentID = adm.RespondentID AND ls.SurveyID = adm.SurveyID
WHERE ls.SurveyID = 1061 AND adm.RespondentID IS NOT NULL
```

The insert command:

```
INSERT INTO [Respondent] ([RespondentID], [SurveyID], [SampleGroupID], [RespondentStatusTypeID], [PilotTest], [Username], [Password], [ImportUniqueID], [WORespID], [DateLastAnswered], [DateCreated], [Email], [Phone], [Name], [JobTitle], [PhoneDirect], [PhoneMobile], [Fax], [CompanyName], [Department], [Address], [Address1], [Address2], [Zipcode], [City], [District], [CountryCode], [Country], [Info1], [Info2], [Info3], [Info4], [Info5], [Info6], [Info7], [Info8], [Info9], [Info10], [Info11], [Info12], [Info13], [Info14], [Info15], [Info16], [Info17], [Info18], [Info19], [Info20], [PublicIdentifier], [LockedByUser], [DialAttempts], [DialProbationExpires], [CATIScreenOptionID], [CATIPersonID], [TotalDuration], [IsExternal])
SELECT ls.[RespondentID], ls.[SurveyID], ls.[SampleGroupID], ls.[RespondentStatusTypeID], ls.[PilotTest], ls.[Username], ls.[Password], ls.[ImportUniqueID], ls.[WORespID], ls.[DateLastAnswered], ls.[DateCreated], ls.[Email], ls.[Phone], ls.[Name], ls.[JobTitle], ls.[PhoneDirect], ls.[PhoneMobile], ls.[Fax], ls.[CompanyName], ls.[Department], ls.[Address], ls.[Address1], ls.[Address2], ls.[Zipcode], ls.[City], ls.[District], ls.[CountryCode], ls.[Country], ls.[Info1], ls.[Info2], ls.[Info3], ls.[Info4], ls.[Info5], ls.[Info6], ls.[Info7], ls.[Info8], ls.[Info9], ls.[Info10], ls.[Info11], ls.[Info12], ls.[Info13], ls.[Info14], ls.[Info15], ls.[Info16], ls.[Info17], ls.[Info18], ls.[Info19], ls.[Info20], ls.[PublicIdentifier], ls.[LockedByUser], ls.[DialAttempts], ls.[DialProbationExpires], ls.[CATIScreenOptionID], ls.[CATIPersonID], ls.[TotalDuration], ls.[IsExternal]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DBName].[dbo].[Respondent] ls LEFT OUTER JOIN [Respondent] adm
ON ls.RespondentID = adm.RespondentID AND ls.SurveyID = adm.SurveyID
WHERE ls.SurveyID = 1061
AND adm.RespondentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build such a system myself before, but it turned out to be a disaster. What I use to sync data between database is a Redgate tool called [SQL data Compare,](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

Comment: We use this too, but we also need to do the synchronization in code

Comment: what do you mean with in code? Do you have your queries hard coded in your code instead of in stored procedures?

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL Server 2008 or later, you'll want to look at [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), so you can get it down to a single statement.

If this is for something that's occuring regularly, have you considered using built in tools such as replication?